# MEAN stack Facebook authorization error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header?

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to make facebook-authorization on my MEAN stack application. I am using `passport` and `passport-facebook`. I am not using `jade` or `ejs`, I want to use pure angularjs. When I run my application and click "sign in" button, I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%…2Flocalhost%3A3030%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&client_id=....  
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3030' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have made some research and found that node `cors` module may fix this, but it didn't.

**What have I done wrong and how can I fix that?**

Here is my routes.js file (server-side):

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    successRedirect: '/success',
    failureRedirect: '/error'
}));

app.post('/success', function(req, res, next) {
    User.findById(req.session.passport.user, function(err, user) {
        if(err){ 
            res.send({success:false}); 
        }else{ 
            res.send({success:true,user: user});
        }
    });
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
    res.end();
});

app.post('/error', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send({success:false});
});
```

Here is my `passport.js` file (server-side):
**Note:** `clientID`, `clientSectret`, and `callbackURL` is in another file (`config.js`). But they are valid.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: config.facebookAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.facebookAuth.callbackURL
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        User.findOne({ oauthID: profile.id }, function(err, user) {
            if(err) { console.log(err); }
            if (!err && user != null) {
                done(null, user);
            } else {
                var user = new User({
                    oauthID: profile.id,
                    name: profile.displayName,
                    created: Date.now()
                });
                user.save(function(err) {

                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log("saving user ...");
                        done(null, user);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
));


// serialize and deserialize
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializeUser: ' + user._id)
    done(null, user._id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user){
        console.log(user)
        if(!err) {done(null, user);}
        else {done(err, null)}
    });
});
```

And here is my express config file: `express.js` (server-side):

```
var express = require('express'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    cors = require('cors');

var whitelist = ['https://www.facebook.com'];
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function(origin, callback){
    var originIsWhitelisted = whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
    callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
  }
};

module.exports = function (app, config) {
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(bodyParser());
    app.use(cors(corsOptions));
    app.use(session({secret:"car advisor secret"}));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(express.static(config.rootPath+"/public"));
}
```

CLIENT SIDE

Here is my html file:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar-right" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
        <form class="navbar-form" >
            <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="signin()" ng-show="!identity.isAuthenticated()">Sign in</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="signout()" ng-show="identity.isAuthenticated()">Sign out | {{identity.currentUser.name}}</a>
        </form> 
    </div>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
```

Here is my login controller:

```
$scope.signin = function(username, password) {
    authService.authenticateUser(username, password).then(function(success) {
        if (success){
            console.log("You have successfully signed in!");
        }
    });
}

$scope.signout = function() {
    authService.logoutUser().then(function() {
        console.log("You have successfully signed out!");
        $location.path('/');
    });
}
```

And here is my service that handles server communications (authService.js):

```
carApp.factory('authService', function($http, Identity, $q, $cookieStore, $resource) {
return {
    authenticateUser: function(username, password) {
        var dfd = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/auth/facebook').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data.success) {
                    Identity.currentUser = response.data.user;
                    $cookieStore.put('user', response.data.user);
                    dfd.resolve(true);
                } else {
                    $cookieStore.remove('user');
                    dfd.resolve(false);
                }
            });
        return dfd.promise;
    },
    logoutUser: function() {
        var dfd = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/logout').success(function() {
            Identity.currentUser = undefined;
            $cookieStore.remove('user');
            dfd.resolve();
        });
        return dfd.promise;
    }
```

Comment: I am facing similar issue..did you got the solution for this..? can you help me with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make an ajax request to a different address. Even if the address is the same and the port is different, you'll have "same origin policy" problems.

You can do it using nginx and redirecting the request with `proxy_pass`.

Check:
http://distinctplace.com/infrastructure/2013/10/14/internal-redirect-to-another-domain-with-proxy_pass-and-nginx/

something like

```
server
{
  listen 80; 
  server_name localhost;

  location /auth/facebook/request {
    proxy_pass http://(...)facebook.com/(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is misleading at best.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: I wouldn't say misleading but rather incomplete. Yes, using CORS you can make requests to different domains but it has to be allowed by the server. I believe facebook API allows but if OP uses other APIs that maybe doesn't have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header the same problem will appear.
Other reason, for now, to use Nginx is that not all browsers fully support this feature. http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors

Comment: THIS IS WRONG ANWSER!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this solves your problem but i recently went through something similar trying to make a facebook log in for an angular app. make sure in your facebook app setting page,

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your_app_id}/settings/
```

change the "Site URL" to whatever your local host is.for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: Where is "Site URL" settings?

Comment: @Matt facebook UI has changed a lot since I posted this, go to your app dashboard,  select "settings" on the left side, and you will be able to add "domains" and "Site URL"

Answer (score 1):

hello I'm not sure if this help you try

```
    app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider){
      $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
   // $httpProvider.defaults.cache = true;
      $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
   // $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = '';
   // $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = '';
      delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
```